# Jasig CAS Authentication redirect loop

Tags: django, jsp, single-sign-on, cas

I have six applications and I am using Jasig CAS for authenticating them. Jasig CAS's Single Sign On is working  really good for me.

On the other hand, Single Sign Off is not working for me. When I logoff from one of the applications, I can not access to other applications from their root domain but I can access them by using their sub-services.

**Example**:

APP1 = http://domain.com/app1

APP2 = http://domain.com/app2

If I logoff from APP1, I can not reach to http://domain.com/app2  BUT I can reach to http://domain.com/app2/someservice

**Info:**

I am using ProxyPass to direct applications to Jasig CAS.

In Apache CAS web.xml, I have added:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My applications are based on Jsp and Django.

CAS Version : 3.3.10

**----UPDATE----**

I managed to solve 4 out of 6 applications by changing the "Satisfy" parameter of configurations of applications from "any" to "all".

2 out of 6 applications are deployed on Tomcat and to make them run on apache, mod_jk is used. When I try to enter any of those apps I get a redirection loop error. Because

1-) Application request ticket generating tickets from CAS

2-) CAS provides the ticket generating tickets

3-) Application resends ticket generating ticket to get the ticket

4-) CAS redirects to the main start page of the application

5-) Go back to state 1

When I look into the cas.log file I see

FormObjectClass not set.  Using default class of org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentials with formObjectName credentials and validator org.jasig.cas.validation.UsernamePasswordCredentialsValidator.

Error

Any suggestions ?

Comment: my first guess is: http://domain.com/app2/someservice is being cached.

Comment: What is Apache CAS? Do you mean [Jasig CAS](http://jasig.org/cas)?

Comment: Yes I meant that, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use "django-cas-client" as authentication backend?

I'm not sure if you need to configure anything on JaSig CAS side for the single sign-off. It's rather a way of logging out and you're free to use it or not.

You may want to study these article(s):

- http://www.goldmund-wyldebeast-wunderliebe.nl/tech-blog/blog-posts/sso-in-plone-and-django-using-jasig-cas-part1-install-and-cthisonfigure
- http://www.goldmund-wyldebeast-wunderliebe.nl/tech-blog/blog-posts/sso-in-plone-and-django-using-jasig-cas-part2-authentication-in-django-and-plone

Comment: I am using proxypass to use CAS as a gateway to all applications. It works except for those that I used mod_jk to make Tomcat and Apache talk.